# SQL Server slow with AZURE AD authentication

Tags: sql-server, azure-active-directory, sql-server-2014

We have a setup where we have 2 machines.

The first one is a Windows Server with SQL Server 2014 (v12), and the other one is a Windows 7 "client" connecting via SQL Server Management Studio.

Both machines are "physical machine" and not VMS.

If I login on the 2 machines with default windows credentials everything works as expected, but as soon as 1 machine is authenticate with Azure Active Directory, everything becomes really slow.

A `select * from table` that would take 30 seconds to execute becomes a 6 minutes + operation.

I try login in to SQL with default sa user / AAD user / server IP / server name they all have the same behavior.

Comment: By "SQL Server 12" - do you mean SQL Server **2012**, or do you mean SQL Server version 12 (= SQL Server **2014**) - please be more careful when specifying version numbers!

Comment: Sql Server version 12.0.2269